# C++での可変長引数を取る関数の書き方

Tags: c++11

```
std::string localizedFormat(const std::string& format, const std::vector<std::string>& strVector)
{
    std::string ret = format;
    int i = 0;
    for (const std::string& str : strVector) {
        ret = strReplace(ret, "%" + std::to_string(i) + "@", str);
        i++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

上記のような関数を作りました。
これは、format中の%0@、%1@...という文字列を、vectorに入っている文字列で置き換えていく関数です。
(strReplace(str,from,to)という関数は、str中のfrom文字列をto文字列に置き換える関数です。)

使用例

```
std::vector<std::string> vect = {"A","10","B"};
std::string format1 = "%0@ dealt %1@ damage to %2@.";
CCLOG("%s", localizedFormat(format1, vect).c_str());
//"A dealt 10 damage to B."
std::string format2 = "%0@は%2@に%1@のダメージを与えた。";
CCLOG("%s", localizedFormat(format2, vect).c_str());
//AはBに10のダメージを与えた。
```

これはゲームのメッセージをローカライズするために作った関数で、format中の置換する位置が前後することがあるので、数字で置換する位置を指定しています。

これを
std::string localizedFormat(const std::string& format, const std::string& str,...)
という可変長引数を取る関数にしたいのですが、どう書けばいいでしょうか。

できれば、Cのva_listとかを使うやり方でなく、C++の可変長テンプレートを使ったやりかたがいいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的にはこんな感じになるでしょうか。

```
template<typename ... Args>
std::string localizedFormat(const std::string& format, const Args ... strs)
{
    std::vector<std::string> strVector = {strs...};
    return localizedFormat(format, strVector);
}
```

元の`localizedFormat`は残しておいてoverloadする想定で。
(Hidekiさんにコメントで教えていただいた修正を入れておきました。)

Comment: これですと、可変長引数がstringでなくても通ってしまうのですが、引数がstringでないとエラーが出るようにすることはできますか？

Comment: 手元のClangでコンパイルした場合、`std::vector<std::string> strVector {strs...};`を展開した時にエラーになるので「(コンパイルが)通ってしまう」と言うことはないと思います。(エラーが呼び出し側ではなく、テンプレートの方に出てしまいますが。)ただ、全引数がstringとわかっているのに、各引数がバラバラの型で良いような可変長テンプレートにするのはどうか思うのですが、私の知識の範囲内ではC++でstringに限定した可変長引数を表現する方法はわからないですね。

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> strVector {strs...};` のところは `std::vector<std::string> strVector = {strs...};` のように、変数名と初期化リストの間に `=` を入れたほうがいいと思います。元のままだと、例えば `localizedFormat(format, 2U);` と呼び出すと、`std::vector<std::string> strVector {2};` となり要素数を指定するコンストラクタと解釈されコンパイルが通ってしまいます。

Comment: @Hideki さん、 `localizedFormat(format, 2);`でエラーになったんで、『「(コンパイルが)通ってしまう」と言うことはない』と書いてしまいましたが、確かにそれだと通ってしまいますね。回答を修正しておきます。